# How to make my keyup function work inside of my game

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is somewhat a long shot, but I have been recently working on a game, and I have been pretty proud of it. Although it is no Minecraft, for my level of expertise, it is looking pretty good. There is just one problem with it though. My character travels all over the place. I have never been able to get him to only move one block. If there is anyone out there with a high level of coding expertise, please look at this code. There is a lot of code, so it might take a while, but I appreciate all the help I can get. If you can spot the problem, please notify me. Thank you.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

setInterval(terrainJumpLoop, 100);
setInterval(playerLeftLoop, 100);
setInterval(playerRightLoop, 100);

canvas.width = 1500;
canvas.height = 500;

var highTerrain = [];
var middleTerrain = [];
var lowTerrain = [];
var oreTerrain = [];

var biome = "";
var biomeSelector = 0;
var playerBlock = 0;
var terrainLength = canvas.width/25;
var unevenTerrainLocator = 0;
var gravityVar = 0;
var gravityStrength = 0;
var touchingGround = false;
var canMove = true;
var gameOn = false;

window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "Game has Stopped Abruptly Due to Error in Code";
    document.getElementById("wrongCodeLine").innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById("errorLineNo").innerHTML = "Line Number: " + lineNo.toString();
    window.stop();
};

var Player = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:25,
    height:25,
    color:"gold"
};

function paintGameTrees(x, y){
    alert(x);
    alert(y);
}

function paintGameTerrain(){
    var grassBlock = {
        width:25,
        height:25,
        color:"green"
    };

    var dirtBlock = {
        width:25,
        height:25,
        color:"brown"
    };

    var stoneBlock = {
        width:25,
        height:25,
        color:"gray"
    };

    var coalBlock = {
        width:25,
        height:25,
        color:"#383838"
    };

    var ironBlock = {
      width:25,
      height:25,
      color:"#C0C0C0"
    };

    var lava = {
        width:25,
        height:25,
        color:"red"
    };

    var snowBlock = {
        width:25,
        height:25,
        color:"white"
    };

    for(i = 0; i < terrainLength; i++){
        if(highTerrain[i] === 0){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 100, grassBlock.width, grassBlock.height, grassBlock.color);
        }
        else if(highTerrain[i] === 7){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 100, snowBlock.width, snowBlock.height, snowBlock.color);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < terrainLength; i++){
        if(middleTerrain[i] === 0){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 75, grassBlock.width, grassBlock.height, grassBlock.color);
        }
        else if(middleTerrain[i] === 1){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 75, dirtBlock.width, dirtBlock.height, dirtBlock.color);
        }
        else if(middleTerrain[i] === 7){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 75, snowBlock.width, snowBlock.height, snowBlock.color);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < terrainLength; i++){
        if(lowTerrain[i] === 0){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 50, grassBlock.width, grassBlock.height, grassBlock.color);
        }
        else if(lowTerrain[i] === 1){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 50, dirtBlock.width, dirtBlock.height, dirtBlock.color);
        }
        else if(lowTerrain[i] === 2){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 50, stoneBlock.width, stoneBlock.height, stoneBlock.color);
        }
        else if(lowTerrain[i] === 7){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 50, snowBlock.width, snowBlock.height, snowBlock.color);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < terrainLength; i++){
        if(oreTerrain[i] === 2){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 25, stoneBlock.width, stoneBlock.height, stoneBlock.color);
        }

        else if(oreTerrain[i] === 4){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 25, coalBlock.width, coalBlock.height, coalBlock.color);
        }

        else if(oreTerrain[i] === 5){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 25, ironBlock.width, ironBlock.height, ironBlock.color);
        }
        else if(oreTerrain[i] === 6){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 25, lava.width, lava.height, lava.color)
        }
        else if(oreTerrain[i] === 7){
            paintGameItems(i*25, canvas.height - 25, lava.width, lava.height, lava.color)
        }
    }
}

function setItemAttributes(){
    console.log("ItemAttributes Successfully Set");
    paintGameItems(Player.x, Player.y, Player.width, Player.height, Player.color);
    console.log("paintGameItems Successfully Called");
}

function randomTerrain(){
    console.log("randomTerrain successfully called");

    /*
    If the number passed is 0, then the block will be grass
    If the number 1 is passed, then the block will be dirt
    If the number 2 is passed, then the block will be stone
    If the number 3 is passed, then the block will be nothing
    If the number 4 is passed, then the block will be coal
    If the number 5 is passed, then the block will be iron
    If the number 6 is passed, then the block will be lava
    If the number 7 is passed, then the block will be snow
    */

    var terrainVar = Math.random() * 10;
    var oreVar = Math.random() * 10;

    if(biome === "plains") {
        if (terrainVar > 0 && terrainVar < 6) {
            highTerrain.push(0);
            middleTerrain.push(1);
            lowTerrain.push(2)
        } else if (terrainVar > 6 && terrainVar < 9) {
            highTerrain.push(3);
            middleTerrain.push(0);
            lowTerrain.push(1);
        } else {
            highTerrain.push(3);
            middleTerrain.push(3);
            lowTerrain.push(0);
        }

        console.log("oreVar = " + oreVar);

        if (oreVar < 6) {
            oreTerrain.push(2);
        } else if (oreVar > 6 && oreVar < 8) {
            oreTerrain.push(4);
        } else if (oreVar > 8 && oreVar < 9) {
            oreTerrain.push(5);
        } else if (oreVar > 9) {
            oreTerrain.push(6)
        }
    }

    else if(biome === "taiga") {
        if (terrainVar > 0 && terrainVar < 6) {
            highTerrain.push(7);
            middleTerrain.push(7);
            lowTerrain.push(2)
        } else if (terrainVar > 6 && terrainVar < 9) {
            highTerrain.push(3);
            middleTerrain.push(7);
            lowTerrain.push(7);
        } else {
            highTerrain.push(3);
            middleTerrain.push(3);
            lowTerrain.push(7);
        }

        console.log("oreVar = " + oreVar);

        if (oreVar < 6) {
            oreTerrain.push(2);
        } else if (oreVar > 6 && oreVar < 8) {
            oreTerrain.push(4);
        } else if (oreVar > 8 && oreVar < 9) {
            oreTerrain.push(5);
        } else if (oreVar > 9) {
            oreTerrain.push(6)
        }
    }
}

function paintGameItems(itemX, itemY, itemWidth, itemHeight, itemColor){
    //console.log(itemX, itemY, itemWidth, itemHeight);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = itemColor;
    ctx.fillRect(itemX, itemY, itemWidth, itemHeight);
    ctx.fill();
}

function selectBiome(){
    biomeSelector = Math.random() * 10;

    if(biomeSelector <= 7){
        biome = "plains";
    }

    else if(biomeSelector > 7){
        biome = "taiga";
    }
}

function playerLocationTracker(){
    console.log("Player.x = " + Player.x + ". canMove = " + canMove + ". playerBlock = " + playerBlock);
}

function playerJump(e){
    addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 87 || e.keyCode === 38) {
            if (touchingGround) {
                for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    Player.y -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function playerLeft(e){
    addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(canMove) {
            if (e.keyCode === 65 || e.keyCode === 37){
                console.log("Left");
                canMove = false;
                playerBlock -= 0.04;
                Player.x -= 0.4;
                canMove = true;
                e.keyCode = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}

function playerRight(e){
    addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (canMove){
            if (e.keyCode === 68 || e.keyCode === 39) {
                console.log("Right");
                canMove = false;
                playerBlock += 0.04;
                Player.x += 0.4;
                canMove = true;
                e.keyCode = 0;

            }
        }
    });
}

function playerGravity(){
    unevenTerrainLocator = Math.round(playerBlock);
    if(highTerrain[unevenTerrainLocator] === 0 || highTerrain[unevenTerrainLocator] === 7){
        gravityVar = canvas.height - 12;
    }
    else if(middleTerrain[unevenTerrainLocator] === 0 || middleTerrain[unevenTerrainLocator] === 7){
        gravityVar = canvas.height - 100;
    }
    else if(lowTerrain[unevenTerrainLocator] === 0 || lowTerrain[unevenTerrainLocator] === 7){
        gravityVar = canvas.height - 75
    }

    if(gravityVar <= Player.y){
        Player.y = gravityVar;
        gravityStrength = 0;
        touchingGround = true;
    }
    else if(gravityVar > Player.y){
        touchingGround = false;
        gravityStrength +=5;
        Player.y += gravityStrength;
    }
}

function terrainJumpLoop(){
    if(gameOn){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        playerGravity();
        playerJump();
        playerLocationTracker();
        paintGameItems(Player.x, Player.y, Player.width, Player.height, Player.color);
        paintGameTerrain();
    }
}

function playerLeftLoop(){
    playerLeft();
}

function playerRightLoop(){
    playerRight();
}

function initializeGame(){
    var treeX = (Math.round(Math.random()*(canvas.width/25)))*25;
    var treeY = 0;
    if(highTerrain[treeX/25] === 0){
        treeY = canvas.height - 100;
    }
    else if(middleTerrain[treeX/25] === 0){
        treeY = canvas.height - 75;
    }
    else if(lowTerrain[treeX/25]){
        treeY = canvas.height - 50;
    }

    paintGameTrees(treeX, treeY);

    if (biome === "plains") {
        document.getElementById('mediaOverworld').play();
    }
    else if(biome === "taiga"){
        document.getElementById('mediaGlaciers').play();
    }
}

function startGameFunction() {
    console.clear();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    document.getElementById('mediaOverworld').pause();
    document.getElementById('mediaOverworld').currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById('mediaGlaciers').pause();
    document.getElementById('mediaGlaciers').currentTime = 0;
    highTerrain = [];
    middleTerrain = [];
    lowTerrain = [];
    oreTerrain = [];
    selectBiome();
    Player.x = 0;
    Player.y = 0;
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "Music and Game Has Successfully Started";
    console.log("Game Has Successfully Started");
    setItemAttributes();
    for(i = 0; i < terrainLength; i++){
        randomTerrain();
        console.log("Terrain Layer Successfully Generated")
    }
    console.log(highTerrain);
    console.log(middleTerrain);
    console.log(lowTerrain);
    console.log(oreTerrain);
    initializeGame();
    paintGameTerrain();
    document.getElementById("startBtn").innerHTML = "Reset the Game";
    gameOn = true;
}
```

```css
body{
     background-color:black;
     color:white;
 }

canvas{
    background-color:aqua;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#ifError {
    color: red;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple 2D JavaScript Platformer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="startGameFunction()" id="startBtn">Start The Game</button>
<p id="paragraph"></p>
<div id="ifError">
    <p id="wrongCodeLine"></p>
    <p id="errorLineNo"></p>
</div>
<audio id="mediaOverworld">
    <source src="Audio/Overworld.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="mediaGlaciers">
    <source src="Audio/Glaciers.mp3">
</audio>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a lot of code to debug, but if you can do it, I will thank you a lot.

Comment: you have no "keyup" function in the code - perhaps you need to write this function you are having a problem with?